# How do I implement hook_finder_goto_alter()?

Tags: hooks

I'm having a bit of trouble with troubleshooting a module I am working. I am trying to modify a module to redirect traffic but even though its enabled it doesn't seem to do anything.  I've had problems in the past with using hooks and i'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I am basically using the finder module and here's the code to redirect:

```
function test_finder_goto_alter(&$result, $finder) {
  /* Redirect to a different page in the current directory that was requested */
    drupal_goto("testpage");
}
```

I see the module in modules and enabled it but it still doesn't redirect the way I want it to.  Do you have any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong? I don't think its specific to this module I think I might be doing something wrong in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementations of `hook_*_alter()` are generally supposed the first parameter passed as reference, not to execute `drupal_goto()`, or any other functions that redirect the user.

Looking at the code of the Finder module, I notice that the following code is one that handles the hook you implemented.

```
$base_module = &$finder->base_handler['#module'];

if ((isset($finder->go) && $finder->go && count($result)) || ($goto == 'best' && count($result) === 1)) {
  drupal_alter('finder_goto', $result, $finder);
  $current_result = current($result);
  module_invoke($base_module, 'finder_goto', $finder, $current_result);
}
```

Finder calls that hook with [drupal_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_alter/6), which is the function used to invoke such hooks, and it passes the altered argument to the implementation of [hook_finder_goto()](http://www.braksator.com/api/function/hook_finder_goto/6--1) implemented in the `$base_module` module.

Comment: Thanks so much Kiamlaluno.  I tried to work though what you did to understand and although my php is weak, I now understand the code.  My problem is it still doesn't work.  I don't really want the specific answer but was wondering how do you troubleshoot modules? My problem is I am getting no feedback from the module, with java or unix you get errors or can debug, with drupal i'm not sure how to troubleshoot a module.  Is there a package to help code modules? or a way to run it in an monitored environment(like how in netbeans you can debug code)

Comment: @LostSoul You could install Devel, which has some functions that can be used to output as Drupal messages the content of a variable. If you use `dsm($finder)` or `dsm($result)`, you can find the content of those variables.

Comment: I had that installed already.  I kept the goto function still it in and forgot to end with ";" and I got a white screen of death. Thats good because as least I know its aware of my module.  I added the ; and commented out the goto, but I get no output.  Where would I find output of the dsm command?

Comment: when I used dsm to troubleshoot views in the past, it showed up in the preview, but this time there's no preview area.

Comment: @Lostsoul It should be showed the next time a page is rendered by Drupal. In the default theme I use, those messages are shown on the top of the page.

Comment: I'm using the Garland theme, thought that was the default.  Is it safe to say if I'm not getting a message at the top then most likely my hook isn't being executed?  In the future is that a good strategy to first do something like this to make sure my module active and hook is working, then keep outputing the result via the dev command until I get what I want?

Comment: @Lostsoul If you want to verify if your hook is being called, then use `watchdog()`; the messages printed with the function are visible in /admin/reports/dblog, in Drupal 6 and 7.

Comment: been playing around with watchdog..thanks..I'm not getting any results which makes me suspect even more that my hook isn't being executed.  I was re-reading your answer and you said it was in the $base_module module, does that hold any significance? To call a hook, do I need to specifically target that module?

Comment: @Lostsoul No; it's the result of all the implementations of `hook_finder_goto_alter()` that is passed to that module. Therefore, your implementation should be called too. It should be called if the module is test.module, and that code is inside of test.module.

Comment: Thanks after playing around with it, it finally works! Yay my first module..lookout facebook :-)  Thanks so much Kiamlaluno, very kind of you to help so much.

Answer (score 1):

**Hooks 101**

hooks should be created in a module. The module which they are called from should be enabled.

So in the first instance you will need to create a .info and a .module file with the correct information in.

Then to implement a hook you must use the module name.

So the example code above would work if the php code is in a module called *test* which was enabled.

So `hook_menu()` in a module called `test.module` would be a function called `test_menu()`

Secondly hooks will only be called when invoked, some get invoked rarely when for example building the menu system, and others are invoked when specific actions happen. You will need to read up on the documentation for the hook in question to find out more.

The same goes for parameters and return values, each hook is different. So the documentation is important there.

So a general checklist for hooks.

- Is the hook in a module?
- Is the module enabled?
- Is the hook named the same as the
  module?
- Is the action which is calling the
  hook being called?
- Have I cleared the cache?
- Am I using the hook in the correct way?

Comment: Awesome thank you as always Jeremy.  I just printed this and put it on my wall until I get better at writing modules.

Answer (score 0):

You should clear Drupal cache after you implementing hook.

Go to the admin-> Performance -> Clear cache

Comment: i tried that, but no luck.  While I develop, I actually disable the cache.